# Can not get select list back in struts Action class in java

Tags: java, struts

I have a list i take it from DB and populate to the page using this code

```
DynamicComboCM allPartners = new DynamicComboCM();
allPartners.setAllRecommendedList(daoClass.getAllPartners(ds));
request.setAttribute("allPartners", allPartners);
```

Here `DynamicComboCM`  is bean that contains the property `allRecommendedList` and i populate this list from DB using `daoClass` which returns an `ArrayList` then i set it to request and get it on jsp page like this.

```
    <html:select styleId="partnerListForRecommended" name="Bean2"
    property="bean2Property" size="15" multiple="true">
<html:optionsCollection name="allPartners"
    property="allRecommendedList" label="label" value="value" />
    </html:select>
```

i get the list on jsp as expected, on jsp user moves some records from this list to another list and in this way this list reduced by size as some recoreds had move to other list. now when i press save button i m not getting this list,

can any one please help me how to get this list again in jsp, i tried it using `request.getAttribute("allPartners");`  but not working.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- One of solution is to put list `allPartners` into session.

  to set
  `request.getSession().setAttribute("allPartners", allPartners);`

  to get when needed
  `request.getSession().getAttribute("allPartners");`
- Another solution (using request scope) is to get `allPartners` from database again (better from the cache).